# Placement of two direct object pronouns in French

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, coordination

In French how would you say

> I eat you and it.

(Sorry for sentence I can't think of another transitive verb right now)

Would you say

> Je te le mange.

or

> Je te mange et lui.

or

> Je le mange et toi.

Answer (score 3):

> Je vous mange, toi et lui/ça.

or simply:

> Je vous mange tous les deux.

If you want the singular, you might say :

> Je te mange, et elle/lui/ça aussi.
>
> Je le/la mange, et toi aussi.

Note that without knowing what "it" refers to in your sentence, and to a lesser extent, who/what is "you" too, it is difficult to guess how to properly translate this English sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually impossible to directly combine object pronouns in French, or combine a pronoun with a noun! The object pronoun must come before the verb, but only a single object pronoun can be put before a verb. Taking a more meaningful verb:

> Je te vois.
>   Je le vois.
>   Je vois Alice et Benjamin.
>   *<s>Je vois toi (et …).</s>

A workaround is required: use a single pronoun that works — for *toi* and a third person, that's the second person plural pronoun *vous* — and then affix a clause repeating the object.

> Je vous vois, toi et lui.
>   Je les vois, Alice et lui.

None of your ideas work. “**Je te le vois*” would be “I see it at/for/to/… you”, i.e. *te* is an indirect complement, which isn't what you meant, and doesn't work because the verb doesn't take an indirect complement. (Actually, “*Je te le mange*” can be idiomatic French in some contexts, meaning “I eat it for you” — an indirect complement that is a pronoun can sometimes have the implied meaning of taking an action for the sake of someone else.) “**Je te mange et lui*” and “**Je le mange et toi*” don't work, the second pronoun can't be a complement of the first verb. It could be an incomplete sentence like “*Je te mange et lui nous regarde*”, where the second pronoun is the subject of another verb, and the word *et* separates two verb clauses, not two noun clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Je te mange, ainsi que ça.

Je te mange, et ça aussi (moins stylé).

Je mange, et toi, et ça (insiste sur le fait qu'il y a 2 COD).

Je vous mange, toi et ça (agrégation des deux COD).